# Native command line Error while trying to execute c++ on windows (compiled via MinGW)

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, g++, mingw

I'm a complete beginner and I was doing this simple pattern program(using VScode) and getting this error:

```
Program 'pattern.exe' failed to run: Access is deniedAt line:1 char:81
+ ... ++\" ; if ($?) { g++ pattern.cpp -o pattern } ; if ($?) { .\pattern }
+                                                               ~~~~~~~~~. 
At line:1 char:81
+ ... ++\" ; if ($?) { g++ pattern.cpp -o pattern } ; if ($?) { .\pattern }
+                                                               ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed
```

The code:

```
# include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int row;
    cout<<"Enter row:";
    cin>>row;
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        cout<<"*"<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

System Info:

```
system type: x64-based PC
```

result of `g++ --version`

```
g++ (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Downloaded MinGW from:(https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/)
I have Quick heal internet security and whenever I run this program it shows message like this `Trojan.GenericIH.S13099362`
It says 'File successfully repaired' but error is coming again!!
Thanks for the help!!

Comment: I think you have to see why you have no permission to run the program you created. Make sure you did not use "Run As Administrator" ever with your program or VSCode. If this is not the case try disabling your Antivirus.

Comment: ***I have Quick heal internet security and whenever I run this program it shows message like this Trojan.GenericIH.S13099362*** Tell your antivirus to exclude the folder that you have your code in.

Comment: yes, sir. It is not set on 'Run As Administrator' and my bro don't allow me to disable antivirus!

Comment: Your code is not a virus. Some AV do falsely detect c++ programs as suspicious. If you can't disable your antivirus you probably need to move to running your code under linux / WSL or move to a different machine where the AV is not falsely detecting your programs as a virus. Or in some type of container like having a windows instance inside a Virtual Box instance.

Comment: yes, sir. I'll do my best!! Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score -1):

Using a Windows native command prompt, you can invoke an executable directly without the `./` or `.\` at the beginning.